# Multi language support for Client Side webpart with New SharePoint Development Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have created a sample Hello world webpart using the Examples provided at [Office site](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Webpart has a Property called "Description" in Property Pane which displayed in English Language.

I would like to display in "Description" in German language for German User. Is it possible to do so, I try to refer [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library) Page to get understanding of how Resource Localisation works, but not got much Help.

I wanted to know is it possible if i force in my code to load specfic Language Resource file. Currently in Config.json of the solution I have

"localizedResources": {
    "expStrings": "webparts/exp/loc/{locals}.js"
  }

Under the Resource files i have en-us.js and de-de.js , how i can force code to load de-de.js instead of en-us.js.

I have requirement to Display the Webpart Description based on Users Language.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

When starting the workbench by default it uses the en-US locale. To override this you can run:

`$ gulp serve --locale=de-de`

which will cause the workbench to use the **de-DE** locale instead.

Another way to test it, is to use the hosted version of workbench in the context of a German site. In O365 create a new Team Site using the de-DE locale (let's say its URL is https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite). Then you would open the workbench using **https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx** which would be using the **de-DE** locale.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have scenario like same site collection  will be used across globe but we have to translate the webpart Title based on the User Preferred Locale, is there any way we can force to load the respective Locale via code?

Comment: You mean the title displayed in the toolbox when adding the web part to the page? SharePoint Framework automatically loads the resource file corresponding to the current locale so there is no need for you to force it.